# Pandas Convert a column in the format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ" to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which has a column containing strings of the format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

When I do the following operation

```
df["updatedTimeDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: time data 'last_update_date_time' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ' (match)
```

I ran the command

```
print (df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df["token_last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='coerce').isna(),'token_last_update_date_time'])
```

and got the following output

```
0    token_last_update_date_time
Name: token_last_update_date_time, dtype: object
```

On running the following command

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df["token_last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='coerce'))
```

I got the output

```
0                           NaT
1       2023-08-29 18:37:17.686
2       2023-08-29 19:23:25.107
3       2023-08-29 19:10:14.758
4       2023-08-29 18:34:19.377
```

Comment: Could you give an example of one of the strings in your column?

Comment: '2023-08-29T18:37:17.686Z'

Comment: I don't get any error when I use your example code with your example string. Which version of pandas are you using? I have pandas v1.5.3.

Comment: I am using 1.4.4

Comment: I have tested it w/o any issue on pandas v1.5.1. Maybe you can try `http://github.com/mps-youtube/yewtube/issues/1086`

Comment: why use a literal 'Z' in the `format` ? that will make the parser ignore the fact that the input is UTC (which I'd consider bad practice - you can always localize to None later on, to explicitly state what's going on). Besides, pandas >= 2.0 has `format="ISO8601"` for that kind of input format, to speed things up ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the problem:

#### Possible Causes:

1. **Mismatched Format**: The most obvious cause is that some strings in the
   `last_update_date_time` column do not match the format `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`.
   This could be due to **missing values, different date-time formats, or other unexpected string values.**
2. **Presence of NaN or None Values**: If your dataframe has `NaN` or `None` values in the
   `last_update_date_time` column, `pd.to_datetime` will raise a `ValueError` when a format is specified.

#### Solution:

To address the above causes, you can:

1. **Handle NaN or None Values**: Use the `errors` parameter in `pd.to_datetime`
   to handle errors gracefully. The `errors` parameter can be set to one of the
   following values:

   - `'raise'` (default): invalid parsings will raise an exception.
   - `'coerce'`: Invalid parsing are set as `NaT` (**N**ot **a** **T**imestamp).
   - `'ignore'`: Invalid parsing return the unmodified input.
2. **Let Pandas Infer the datetime format:** Set the `infer_datetime_format` parameter
   from `pandas.to_datetime` to `True`. Be aware that if you set `infer_datetime_format` to
   `True`, no `format` option can be specified.

Here are two possible ways to addresses these points:

**Option 1:**

```py
# Convert to datetime, handling errors gracefully
# This will convert valid date-times and set invalid ones to NaT (Not a Timestamp)
df["updatedTimeDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"],
                                           format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',
                                           errors='coerce')
```

By setting `errors='coerce'`, any invalid parsing will be set as `NaT`,
which allows you to identify and handle these anomalies separately.

**Option 2:**

Another option is to set the `infer_datetime_format` parameter from `pandas.to_datetime` to `True`.
When `infer_datetime_format` is set to `True`, **and no `format` is given**,
Pandas will attempt to infer the format of the datetime strings based on the first
non-NaN element, and if it can be inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them.

```py
df["updatedTimeDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
```

**Finding Values that Could not be Converted:**

After this conversion, you can inspect rows with `NaT` values in the `'updatedTimeDateTime'`
column to understand and address the specific issues:

```py
invalid_rows = df[df["updatedTimeDateTime"].isna() & df["last_update_date_time"].notna()]
print(invalid_rows)
```

This will give you rows where the original date-time was not null,
but the conversion resulted in `NaT`, indicating a format mismatch or other issue.

#### Source Code

Creating dummy string dates and testing the solutions detailed above:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data
data = {
    'last_update_date_time': [
        '2023-09-07T12:34:56.789Z',  # Valid
        '2023-09-07T12:34:56Z',      # Missing milliseconds
        '2023-09-07 12:34:56.789Z',  # Space instead of 'T'
        '2023-09-07T12:34:56.78Z',   # 2 digits in milliseconds
        'InvalidString',             # Completely invalid
        None,                        # None value
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# -- Option 1: handling errors gracefully ----------------------------------------
# Convert to datetime, handling errors gracefully
df["updatedTimeDateTime_option1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"],
                                           format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',
                                           errors='coerce')

# Inspect values that could not be parsed by filtering rows with NaT values
invalid_datetimes = df.loc[df["updatedTimeDateTime_option1"].isna()
                           & df["last_update_date_time"].notna(),
                           "last_update_date_time"]

print(f"{' Option 1 ':=^60}")
print("Invalid Rows:", invalid_datetimes.values)
print()

# -- Option 2: automatic date format inference -----------------------------------
df["updatedTimeDateTime_option2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"],
                                                   infer_datetime_format=True,
                                                   errors='coerce')

# Inspect values that could not be parsed by filtering rows with NaT values
invalid_datetimes = df.loc[df["updatedTimeDateTime_option2"].isna()
                           & df["last_update_date_time"].notna(),
                           "last_update_date_time"]

print(f"{' Option 2 ':=^60}")
print("Invalid Rows:", invalid_datetimes.values)
```

**Solutions Comparisson:**

| **last_update_date_time** | **updatedTimeDateTime_option1** | **updatedTimeDateTime_option2** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-07T12:34:56.789Z | 2023-09-07 12:34:56.789000 | 2023-09-07 12:34:56.789000+00:00 |
| 2023-09-07T12:34:56Z | NaT | 2023-09-07 12:34:56+00:00 |
| 2023-09-07 12:34:56.789Z | NaT | 2023-09-07 12:34:56.789000+00:00 |
| 2023-09-07T12:34:56.78Z | 2023-09-07 12:34:56.780000 | 2023-09-07 12:34:56.780000+00:00 |
| InvalidString | NaT | NaT |
|  | NaT | NaT |

Comment: `infer_datetime_format` is deprecated since pandas 2.0.0

Answer (score 4):

If need check what values not match your format use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'last_update_date_time':['2023-08-29T18:37:17.686Z',
                                            '2023-08-30T18:37:17.686Z',
                                            '2023-09-01']})
```

---

```
print (df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='coerce').isna(),'last_update_date_time'])
2    2023-09-01
Name: last_update_date_time, dtype: object
```

If need replace not matched values to `NaT`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='coerce'))
0   2023-08-29 18:37:17.686
1   2023-08-30 18:37:17.686
2                       NaT
Name: last_update_date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If there is also another format, e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD` use:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["last_update_date_time"], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')))
0   2023-08-29 18:37:17.686
1   2023-08-30 18:37:17.686
2   2023-09-01 00:00:00.000
Name: last_update_date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

EDIT: Output of testing not matched values:

```
0    token_last_update_date_time
Name: token_last_update_date_time, dtype: object
```

You can remove first row of DataFrame:

```
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or replace first value of column to `NaT` by solution above.